# Apply javascript (add row) to 2 different form fields

Tags: javascript, forms

This is all new to me and i don't have that much (or even none) knowledge of javascript. I hoped someone could help me out? I have 2 different form fields and i would like to apply a script to the 2 different form fields.
The thing is to add an extra form row. I found this script on-line and hoped to get it work for both fields.

These are the forms:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 100%;" id="card-elements">
                <h5 class="card-header">Ingredients</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="ingredients-contents">
                        <form method="post" action="">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div id="inputFormRow-ingredients">
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <input type="text" name="ingredient[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Add ingredient" autocomplete="off">
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="newRow"></div>
                                    <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Ingredient</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;" id="card-elements">
                <h5 class="card-header">Steps</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="steps-contents">
                        <form method="post" action="">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div id="inputFormRow-steps">
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <input type="text" name="ingredient[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Add Step" autocomplete="off">
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="newRow"></div>
                                    <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Step</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the script i'm using:

```
 // add row
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
    html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
    html += '<input type="text" name="ingredient[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Add ingredient" autocomplete="off">';
    html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
    html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#newRow').append(html);
});

// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in 2 places you have `<div id="newRow"></div>` I don't think this is what you want. first one should be `<div id="newRow-ingredients"></div>` and the other one `<div id="newRow-steps"></div>`

and then you would have

```
$('#newRow-ingredients').append(html);
```

and adding the other field would be: (with other html)

```
$('#newRow-steps').append(html);
```

also don't use ID's unless you really need them. Always use classes 99% of the time, in your situation that would also be a problem because ID's have to be unique and you are using them multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You're re-using the same `id` values throughout your code.  So when you select an element by its `id` like so:

```
$("#addRow")
```

Which element are you expecting that selector to target and why?

To convert this to something that can be used multiple times on a page, your best bet is usually to switch from using an `id` to using a `class`.  In your code that'll involve a few changes.  First, change the `addRow` `id` values to `class` values:

```
<div class="newRow"></div>
<button type="button" class="addRow btn btn-info">Add Ingredient</button>
```

And target that selector:

```
$(".addRow").click(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Within that click handler function, replace the `id` values with `class` values in the HTML being created:

```
html += '<div class="inputFormRow">';
//...
html += '<button type="button" class="removeRow btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button>';
```

The interesting bit is the last line of that function, because you'll need to target a specific instance of `.newRow`.  You can use the jQuery `.siblings()` function to find the one you want:

```
$(this).siblings(".newRow").append(html);
```

Then in the remove functionality switching to `class` selectors should do the trick:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('.inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

Throughout this, the main thing to keep in mind when switching from `id` to `class` so you can re-use the functionality throughout the page is to change the mindset from "globally target this specific element" to one of two concepts:

- Globally target all of these elements; or...
- Relatively target this specific element, by traversing the DOM from where I am now.

An example of the first one is adding the click handler to all matching `.addRow` elements.  An example of the second one is already present in the use of `.closest()`, and was also added here in the use of `.siblings()`.  There are a variety of jQuery DOM traversal functions to help find a specific element you're looking for from the context of the element invoking the event.

---

**Note:** You may still have some work to be done here.  I'm noticing that *all* of your form inputs are still called `ingredient[]`.  So they'll all post as one big array with no difference on the server-side.  If that's not the intent then you'll need to keep making some modifications.

Continuing down the path we've already started here, consider how you might tell this "add row" handler which type of row you want to add.  For example, maybe each `.addRow` element has a data attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="addRow btn btn-info" data-rowType="ingredient">Add Ingredient</button>
```

Then in the handler you can get that data:

```
const rowType = $(this).data('rowType');
```

And use that value in the HTML being built:

```
html += '<input type="text" name="' + rowType + '[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Add ' + rowType + '" autocomplete="off">';
```